# EclipseLink NoSQL & Netbeans connection to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, netbeans, eclipselink, nosql

I'm trying to use MongoDb and Eclipselink as described in the Eclipselink tutorial.

[Link here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/NoSQL)

I've installed the MongoDb Plugin for Netbeans.
Infact, using the standard connection, everything works perfectly

The first problem is in the jdbc driver creation.

I've downloaded from the official MongoDb site the drivers

> mongodb-driver-3.2.1 mongodb-driver-core-3.2.1 mongo-java-driver-3.2.1

When I try to create a new JDBC driver in the Netbeans option using that drivers I find the error "Driver Class is Missing".

The option is to use a proprietary driver UnityJDBC, but I can't because my project must use only open source.

I've found another jdbc driver at [this link](http://www.dbschema.com/mongodb-jdbc-driver.html).
Netbeans seems to accept this as jdbc driver but , it says "Cannot establish a connection to  using com.nosql.NoSqlDriver (Unable to find a suitable driver)"

So the first problem is how to connect using a jdbc.

The second problem is related to the pom dependencies.

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId> 
<version>2.6.2</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>
```

org.eclipse.persistence org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor 2.6.2 
    provided

Do I need more ? 
Because I'm not sure that I need to use both org.eclipse.persistence.nosql and org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

You can't use a 3.x version of the driver to mantain the compatibility with eclipselink.

Secondo question

```
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
```

Only this is necessary